# How to set background color for DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom)?

Tags: swiftui, widgetliveactivity, dynamic-island

I want to set a background color to the bottom area of the expanded Dynamic Island. Like how Flighty does it. How can I do this?

[image: Flighty dynamic island]

I am pretty new to SwiftUI and I can't find anything online that can help me.

Comment: Google "DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom)" gets me some tutorials right away.

Answer (score 0):

[DynamicIslandExpandedRegion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/dynamicislandexpandedregion) takes a `View` in its content closure, so you could simply do it like this:

```swift
DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
    Text("Example")
        .padding()
        .background(Color.green)
}
```

Comment: This still has a black border for the safe areas of the dynamic island